# Properly round using .45 as the event

Tags: python, pandas

```py
testdata = [['itemnumberPrice', 'Markup'],[317, 1.21]]
testdata['basePrice'] = testdata['itemnumberPrice']*testdata['Markup']

def round_Pricing(x):
    i, f = divmod(x,1)
    return int(i + ((f >= 0.45) if (x > 0) else (f > 0.45)))

testdata['basePrice'].apply(round_Pricing)
```

I would like `basePrice = 355` but I am getting a basePrice of `355.357`. The normal .round() will not work, because I need to round on .45 to go up for positive integers. The standard round also depends on the integer being odd or even and I need the rounding to be based on the decimal.

Comment: should `testdata` be a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: Can you give more examples of numbers and how they should be rounded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From your question wording, I understand you want to "round up if decimal >= 0.45, and round down otherwise".

If that is the case, this should work for positive floats:

```py
import math

def round_up_at(num_to_round, round_boundary):
    decimal = num_to_round % 1 # get decimal portion of float

    if decimal > round_boundary or math.isclose(decimal, round_boundary): # .isclose for float precision i.e. ==
        return math.ceil(num_to_round) # round up
    return math.floor(num_to_round) # round down

print(round_up_at(355.44, 0.45)) # -> 355
print(round_up_at(355.45, 0.45)) # -> 356
print(round_up_at(355.46, 0.45)) # -> 356
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So if I had a dataframe with multiple rows, and I am trying to round this way for all items in the column, how would this work? I tried using the '.apply()'  function and it did not work correctly, I am receiving the error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' and I believe this to be from the 'math.isclose(decimal, round_boundary)' part of the function. I created some test data for arbitrary examples: testdata = [['Premium','Baserate'], [317,1.121], [73.55,1.21], [204.13,1.121]]. 

testdata.apply(round_Pricing(testdata['BasePrice'],.45))